# A number is divided evenly by its factors; what to call this number?

Tags: numbers

A number is divided evenly by its factors, then what to call this number with?

For example:
10 is divided evenly by 1, 2 and 5.
1, 2, 5 are the *factors*

Then, how can I denote "10" with a noun?

(I tried searching *math.stackexchange*, but this seems to be too elementary there)

Comment: Any number is divisible by 1 and itself; they are all numbers.

Comment: _All_ numbers are divisible by their factors.

Comment: A number that can be factored is [factorable](https://www.yourdictionary.com/factorable).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question belongs on math. stackexchange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number 10 is a composite number according to the following definition:

> composite number (kəm-pŏz′ĭt)

> An integer that can be divided by at least one other integer besides itself and 1 without leaving a remainder. 24 is a composite number since it can be divided by 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, and 12. No prime numbers are composite numbers. Compare prime number.

https://www.yourdictionary.com/composite-number

A number that can be divided only by itself and 1 without leaving a remainder is a prime number.

Answer (score 4):

10 is a **multiple** of 1, 2, 5, and 10. (Note that every number is a factor and mul,tiple of itself.)

> In science, a multiple is the product of any quantity and an integer.[1][2][3] In other words, for the quantities a and b, we say that b is a multiple of a if b = na for some integer n, which is called the multiplier. If a is not zero, this is equivalent to saying that b/a is an integer.[4][5][6]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_(mathematics)

Comment: This answer agrees with the OED: *2.Multiple (n.) 2. a. Mathematics. A quantity which contains another quantity some number of times without remainder; a quantity which is the product of a given quantity and some other, esp. one which results from multiplying the given quantity by an integer.  Thus 4 is a multiple of 2; 6 is a multiple of 2 and 3; 12 is the lowest common multiple of 2, 3, and 4.*

Answer (score 2):

10 is the **product** of 1, 2, and 5.  Those are all integers. They are also whole numbers.  **Multiplied** together, 1, 2, and 5 make 10.  2 and 5 are 10's **prime factors**.

Here's a website you can look up related terms: [MathIsFun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/product.html).